# Error while executing Python script on AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am attempting to use the following Lambda Function on AWS to automatically import objects from an S3 bucket into an RDS instance as they are uploaded into the bucket.

```
import boto3
import pymysql

s3_cient = boto3.client('s3')

# Read CSV file content from S3 bucket
def read_data_from_s3(event):
    bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
    s3_file_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
    resp = s3_cient.get_object(Bucket="bucket_name", Key=s3_file_name)

    data = resp['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    data = data.split("\n")
    return data

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    rds_endpoint  = "rds-endpoint"
    username = "name"
    password = "pass" # RDS Mysql password
    db_name = "db-name" # RDS MySQL DB name
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(rds_endpoint, user=username, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
    except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
        print("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")

    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO `db`.`table`(`sensor`,`sIP`,`dIP`,`sPort`) VALUES(<{sensor: }>,<{sIP: }>,<{dIP: }>,<{sPort: }>);")
        conn.commit()
    except:
        pass

    data = read_data_from_s3(event)

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        for ent in data: # Iterate over S3 csv file content and insert into MySQL database
            try:
                ent = ent.replace("\n","").split(",")
                print (">>>>>>>"+str(ent))
                cur.execute('insert into db`.`table (sensor,Sip,Dip,sPort) values("'+str(ent[1])+'")')
                conn.commit()
            except:
                continue
        cur.execute("select * from table")
       
        # Display table records
        for row in cur:
            print (row)
    if conn:
        conn.commit()
```

Whenever I run this, I get the following error and I do not understand what I am doing wrong? Would someone be able to clarify my errors?

```
[ERROR] TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 4 keyword-only arguments) were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_endpoint, user=username, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `pymysql.connect` only takes in keyword arguments. You are passing `rds_endpoint` in as a positional argument. The `rds_endpoint` argument should probably passed in as `host=rds_endpoint`.

Comment: Hey James, so I tried your suggestion just now and it seems to have eliminated the error but nothing is happening when the script gets activated?